# Calling a class from another class JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Recently I started using JFrame and I got stuck with calling a class from another class. I would appreciate if someone could help me. Here is the code:
Tools class that contains two inline buttons

```
package test;


import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Tools extends JFrame {
    private JButton exit, reset;
    private JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
    private JPanel jPanel = (JPanel) jFrame.getContentPane();

    public Tools() {
        jPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        exit = new JButton("Exit");
        reset = new JButton("Reset");

        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                board.reset();
            }
        });

        jPanel.add(exit);
        jPanel.add(reset);

    }

}
```

Control class that makes an instance of Tools object and put them at the bottom of the screen(It should do it, but some error happens)

```
    package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Control extends JFrame {

    private Tools tButtons;

    Control() {


        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        JPanel jPanel = (JPanel) jFrame.getContentPane();
        jPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        tButtons = new Tools();


        jPanel.add(tButtons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        jFrame.setVisible(true);
        jFrame.setSize(350, 350);

    }

}
```

And main class:

```
package test;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Control control = new Control();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you are putting a JFrame (Tools) into a JPanel, which obviously is not correct. And you are creating 3 JFrame's: one in Control, one in Tools, and Tools itself. You should use JPanel for Tools and not JFrame.

Comment: I removed JFrame from Tools class, but I don't understand where I am putting a JFrame into a JPanel.

New Tools class and without action listeners:
public class Tools extends JFrame {
 private JButton exit, reset;
 private Board board;
 private JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
 
 public Tools() {
  jPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  
  exit = new JButton("Exit");
  reset = new JButton("Reset");
  
  jPanel.add(exit);
  jPanel.add(reset);
 }
}

Comment: Tools IS a JFrame since it extends JFrame

Comment: It worked when I added main method to Tools class where I just called Tools class: public static void main(String[] args) {
  Tools tools = new Tools();
 } and added these two:
 jFrame.setVisible(true);
  jFrame.setSize(300, 300);

Comment: Obviously it works since it is showing the jFrame inside Tools. What you are trying to do is putting another JFrame (Tools itself) into a JPanel, and show yet another JFrame in Control, which will not work at all. Try understand what a JFrame is and learn more about Object-oriented programming on inheritance before saying the code is not working.

Comment: I understand there should be only one JFrame and it should be in Control Class. But how can I put this exit and reset buttons in JPanel in Control Class if they are already part of Tools class which is JFrame?

Comment: Well then you could add the JPanel inside Tools to the JPanel inside Control. I would not recommend it since it is a poor program design.

Comment: Then I should make reset and exit button in my Control class